# Orchard Menu Item Class

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'm trying to add a menu item Css Class for navigation items, I found this answer on this site which looked promising ([Orchard 1.5 add class or ID in ContentMenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109728/orchard-1-5-add-class-or-id-in-contentmenuitem)) but doesn't seem to work now in version 1.9.2).  (code from link shown below)

```
if (Model.CssClass != null) {
    tag.AddCssClass(Model.ContentItem.Menu.CssClass.Value);
}
```

I have tried that code but looking through the shape tracing tool and can find the value and try to perform the if statement and get a "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference".

Comment: you can just use `tag.AddCssClass("my-css-class")`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Apologize I wasn't clearer in my request.  I'd like to offer the chance to add the class through the admin panel on a per item basis, so adding it directly in an alternate doesn't work.